# Correct way to change value of an item in a list of class objects

Tags: c#, list, class

Given a class like so:

```
 public class Dinosaur
{
    public string Specie { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Dinosaur()
    {

    }
```

And a list like so:

```
        public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>();
```

What is the correct method to change a value in the last item in the list?
This throws an error ("The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has some invalid arguments"):

```
Dinosaurs[Dinosaurs.Last()].Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

As always, thanks in advance! Stackoverflow has been a lifesaver on this project.

Comment: You have to refer to the item by it's index... Maybe try `Dinosaurs[Dinosaurs.Count - 1].Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;` or `Dinosaurs.Last.Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;`

Comment: Made that change and now it's throwing this error: Cannot modify the return value of 'DinosaurIsland.Dinosaur.Location' because it is not a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Dinosaurs.Last()` returns already the last item, so you don't need the indexer at all.

```
Dinosaurs.Last().Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

> Now it's throwing this error: Cannot modify the return value of
>   'DinosaurIsland.Dinosaur.Location' because it is not a variable

This is because the `Point` is a struct and not a reference type.  So you have to create a new point.

```
Point oldLocation = Dinosaurs.Last().Location;
Dinosaurs.Last().Location = new Point { X = pixelMousePositionX, Y = oldLocation.Y };
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now it's throwing this error: Cannot modify the return value of 'DinosaurIsland.Dinosaur.Location' because it is not a variable.

Comment: That's right, in C# structs are immutable (you can't change them after they are made). DataTime is another good example of this.

Answer (score 5):

`Dinosaurs.Last()` returns the last item, not its index, so this:

```
Dinosaurs.Last().Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

If you want to do it by index, then this:

```
Dinosaurs[Dinosaurs.Count - 1].Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any idea why it's now throwing this error: Cannot modify the return value of 'DinosaurIsland.Dinosaur.Location' because it is not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way you're doing it, you have to refer to the item by it's index:

```
Dinosaurs[Dinosaurs.Count - 1].Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

OR just reference the object directly:

```
Dinosaurs.Last().Location.X = pixelMousePositionX;
```

Comment: Any idea why it's now throwing this error: Cannot modify the return value of 'DinosaurIsland.Dinosaur.Location' because it is not a variable.